# Shadowsocks profile configuring in GuixSystem

Tags: terminal, vpn, proxy, guix, shadowsocks

I have this problem in configuring Shadowsocks profile:

```
$ ssserver -c profile.json
/gnu/store/yvjgk9n6xzpr32maq1mqw1ij2vhm9jxb-shadowsocks-2.8.2-0.e332ec9/lib/python3.8/site-packages/shadowsocks/common.py:221: SyntaxWarning: "is" with a literal. Did you mean "=="?
  if addr is "":
/gnu/store/yvjgk9n6xzpr32maq1mqw1ij2vhm9jxb-shadowsocks-2.8.2-0.e332ec9/lib/python3.8/site-packages/shadowsocks/common.py:233: SyntaxWarning: "is" with a literal. Did you mean "=="?
  if len(block) is 1:
/gnu/store/yvjgk9n6xzpr32maq1mqw1ij2vhm9jxb-shadowsocks-2.8.2-0.e332ec9/lib/python3.8/site-packages/shadowsocks/common.py:235: SyntaxWarning: "is not" with a literal. Did you mean "!="?
  while (ip & 1) == 0 and ip is not 0:
INFO: loading config from profile.json
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/gnu/store/yvjgk9n6xzpr32maq1mqw1ij2vhm9jxb-shadowsocks-2.8.2-0.e332ec9/bin/.ssserver-real", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('shadowsocks==3.0.0', 'console_scripts', 'ssserver')()
  File "/gnu/store/yvjgk9n6xzpr32maq1mqw1ij2vhm9jxb-shadowsocks-2.8.2-0.e332ec9/lib/python3.8/site-packages/shadowsocks/server.py", line 34, in main
    config = shell.get_config(False)
  File "/gnu/store/yvjgk9n6xzpr32maq1mqw1ij2vhm9jxb-shadowsocks-2.8.2-0.e332ec9/lib/python3.8/site-packages/shadowsocks/shell.py", line 355, in get_config
    check_config(config, is_local)
  File "/gnu/store/yvjgk9n6xzpr32maq1mqw1ij2vhm9jxb-shadowsocks-2.8.2-0.e332ec9/lib/python3.8/site-packages/shadowsocks/shell.py", line 210, in check_config
    cryptor.try_cipher(config['password'], config['method'],
  File "/gnu/store/yvjgk9n6xzpr32maq1mqw1ij2vhm9jxb-shadowsocks-2.8.2-0.e332ec9/lib/python3.8/site-packages/shadowsocks/cryptor.py", line 51, in try_cipher
    Cryptor(key, method, crypto_path)
  File "/gnu/store/yvjgk9n6xzpr32maq1mqw1ij2vhm9jxb-shadowsocks-2.8.2-0.e332ec9/lib/python3.8/site-packages/shadowsocks/cryptor.py", line 98, in __init__
    self.cipher = self.get_cipher(
  File "/gnu/store/yvjgk9n6xzpr32maq1mqw1ij2vhm9jxb-shadowsocks-2.8.2-0.e332ec9/lib/python3.8/site-packages/shadowsocks/cryptor.py", line 130, in get_cipher
    return m[METHOD_INFO_CRYPTO](method, key, iv, op, self.crypto_path)
  File "/gnu/store/yvjgk9n6xzpr32maq1mqw1ij2vhm9jxb-shadowsocks-2.8.2-0.e332ec9/lib/python3.8/site-packages/shadowsocks/crypto/openssl.py", line 150, in __init__
    OpenSSLCryptoBase.__init__(self, cipher_name, crypto_path)
  File "/gnu/store/yvjgk9n6xzpr32maq1mqw1ij2vhm9jxb-shadowsocks-2.8.2-0.e332ec9/lib/python3.8/site-packages/shadowsocks/crypto/openssl.py", line 98, in __init__
    load_openssl(crypto_path)
  File "/gnu/store/yvjgk9n6xzpr32maq1mqw1ij2vhm9jxb-shadowsocks-2.8.2-0.e332ec9/lib/python3.8/site-packages/shadowsocks/crypto/openssl.py", line 51, in load_openssl
    raise Exception('libcrypto(OpenSSL) not found with path %s' % path)
Exception: libcrypto(OpenSSL) not found with path None
```

What is the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Edit

Someone, who had a better look at the source code than I did at the time of writing this, devised [a patch](http://issues.guix.gnu.org/45106), that has been submitted to Guix upstream.  In other words, this issue will likely soon be resolved.

## Original Post

Looking at the package definition for shadowsocks, it seems rather empty, not even listing OpenSSL as an input or any such thing.  Furthermore, it appears as though shadowsocks wants you to save all those paths in some kind of configuration.

```
config['crypto_path'] = {'openssl': config['libopenssl'],
                         'mbedtls': config['libmbedtls'],
                         'sodium': config['libsodium']}
```

Such tricks may be insanely clever on traditional distros such as those based on Debian et al., but they are thoroughly broken when used in conjunction with any kind of functional package management.  The Guix way of dealing with this kind of issue would be to hardcode the paths to their inputs at build time using `substitute*`.  Your phase could look like the following:

```
  (add-after 'unpack 'patch-crypto-paths
    (lambda* (#:key inputs #:allow-other-keys)
      (substitute* "shadowsocks/shell.py"
        (("config\\['libopenssl'\\]") 
         (string-append (assoc-ref inputs "openssl") "/path/to/libopenssl"))
        [...])
      #t))
```

[Since the above is obviously meant to be Guix code, you can freely use it under the GPLv3+, even though SO would normally mandate CC BY-SA.]

Note, that ending in `#t` may no longer be strictly required as of recently, but I think you'll still find it very often in Guix code.

Comment: If you instead want things to simply work "as is" pointing "openssl" towards `$(HOME)/.guix-profile/lib/libcrypto.so` in the manner that shadowsocks wants you to configure such things would also be a "solution".  For this you'll also have to install openssl into your profile.  I'm not a user of shadowsocks, so I don't really know what it expects you to do here, but as a user of Guix, I can certainly tell, that the package definition should be changed here.